# Remote VisualVM secure authentication

Tags: java, visualvm, jvisualvm

atm I use the following java params to enable remote access for a java application. But everyone who does a port scan can get access. I couldn´t find the params to set a user and password or ip whitelist. How can I do this ?

```
java
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9000
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html) web page, which describes all the required settings for JMX monitoring with authentication.